# What tool do I need to disassemble this 5 speed freewheel

Tags: tools, freewheel

I have a 5 speed freewheel that I need to take of from hub, but the standard freewheel tool that I do have does not fit.

On the freewheel following text is engraved:

UC SHIMANO SIS
MF Z015 China

It seems to me that tool would need to have 12 splines.

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as a "standard freewheel tool" - there are a half-dozen different schemes, and a similar number for more modern "freehubs".  But that appears to be a standard Shimano unit, a Park FR-1.

Comment: I have freewheel tool that came as part of toolkit, and is intended for standard Shimano freewheels, but this freewheel has smaller inner diameter by millimeter or two, and tool does not fit in. So I am looking for tool for this particular freewheel, since generic Shimano one does not fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a bunch of forum posts from people with similar problems. Shimano freewheels made prior to about 1985 have smaller diameters, about 20mm instead of 22-23mm that they have today.

A search for "Shimano freewheel remover 20mm" brings up some useful results. It looks like Bicycle Research Tools makes a remover called the CT-4 which is designed for older Shimano freeheels.

Good Luck!

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We prefer that answer posts be self-contained on this site. Please consider editing in a summary of the information provided in the links that you gave. That way, the post is still useful if the links die.

Answer (score 3):

Kengine FR-04 Old Style Shimano Freewheel Remover Bike Tool fits FFS TL-FW20

This is what you need.  It has 12 splines and is 20mm diameter. it is being sold on Ebay by the_bikesmiths. I hope this helps. it took me awhile to find it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question Sir.
The tool you need is a "Pin Tool"
There are various brands that make them.
My choice is Park Tool SPA-2 for the Shimano & Campagnolo free-wheel sprocket cassettes.
RJ-The Bike Guy on YouTube has an excellent video on the disassembly & service of this type of hub. Be sure to see this before you start if you've never done this before.
Good Luck - but once you've seen how it is rather easy.
Cheers
Peter Leid

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Yes, the question title says "disassemble" but if you read the actual question it seeks instead to remove the freewheel from the hub.  You may wish to update your answer to match the question.